# ItemAdded not firing with REST

Tags: rest, event-receivers

I have an `ItemAdded` on a list which creates a Document Library for each item added, and updates some fields of the item.

It fires perfectly when items are entered manually.

It doesn't fire when items are added via REST - for testing sake I am authenticating with system administrator account.

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Any hint?

**UPDATE**

The client is a Linux VM running a python REST client.
Both the SP and the Linux VMs are connected to a 192.168.21.x network; digging into the logs with ULS I see many "*Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri http://192.168.21.8:25011/*"

I'm investigating on AAM

Answer (score 1):

AAM was the answer.
The starting point is [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx)